# __init__.py and import dependencies

Tags: python

Is it a good idea or good programming practice to check the dependencies of a module in the `__init__.py` file for a module?

So if I have something in my `__init__.py` file as follows:

```
import imp
modules = set(["numpy", "scipy.spatial.distance"])
for m in modules:
    try:
        imp.find_module(m)
    except ImportError:
        print("Missing dependency: " + str(m))
```

Is this a good practice or is there a more pythonic way to handle this?

Comment: If those modules are essential for your package, you should raise an exception. If they are not essential, then expose some feature flags, and/or raise exceptions when trying to features that require them, and/or raise warnings. `print()` is for humans, Python packages are for Python code.

Comment: What do you think is the advantage of doing this over simply letting each module do a straight `import`?

Comment: Ah yes, so I should actually raise a fatal exception. Of course. Thank you!

Comment: @deceze: That is a good point. I guess my motivation was to make the error message more explicit.

Comment: How much more explicit than `ImportError: No module named 'foo'` can it get...!? ;-P

Comment: That is a fair comment. I guess I was over-thinking it!

Comment: Alos, using a `set` instead of a simple `list` in your example code is unnecessary and provides no advantages to justify its use.

Comment: I love how people upvote questions like this, only because it's about Python...

Comment: For non-essential modules or optional modules I would output a warning. See the `warnings` module in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I myself would leave all that out. I would simply import the modules, because Python itself raises an exeption if a module is not found.

*(Sorry I can't commit on the message above I have few points.)*